# Sign a JWT with a SHA cert using jose4j

Tags: certificate, jwt, private-key, sha

New to using jose4j.  I have found examples like this to set private key from cert:

```
JsonWebSignature jws = new JsonWebSignature();
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec =
new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey pk = kf.generatePrivate(spec);
jws.setKey(kf.generatePrivate(spec));
```

But I get this error message

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
```

I think it is because the cert was created as SHA256 instead of RSA.  Here is how I was told the cert was created:

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 730 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private.key -out certificate_pub.crt
```

Does anyone have any examples of how I could sign JWT with a SHA256 cert?

Comment: The *certificate* is signed with SHA256 *and* RSA, but the *private key*, which you use for signing, does not use any hash and is only RSA. (If it was *encrypted* the PBE would include some hashing, but that's not selectable.) For recent versions (1.0.0 and up) most `openssl` commandline operations, including this one, write privatekey in PKCS#8 format in PEM. Is the first line of the file *readable characters* `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`? Did you (or whoever) **use 1.0.0+ and** did you **convert the PEM to binary** before putting it in `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`?

Comment: The cert file is readable and does begin with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----....  I also tried removing this and -----END RSA from the file and run but it did not help.  Below is the code I used to read the private key        file:String filename = "C:\\private.key";           
     File f = new File(filename);
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
     DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
     byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int)f.length()];
     dis.readFully(keyBytes);

Answer (score 2):

With additional info, that private key file is **PEM but NOT PKCS#8**, as a modern version of OpenSSL should have created for `req -newkey`. And the difference between PEM and "DER" (binary) which standard Java requires is not just removing (and adding) the BEGIN and END lines.

Your simplest solution if OpenSSL is available is to convert *both* of these, without encrypting:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -outform der -in private.pem -out good.der
```

Then read `good.der` (use better name if you like) as bytes, and put that in `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` and use it as you posted. Aside: you don't need to fiddle with `DataInputStream`, which isn't really intended for "plain old" bytes; `java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes` can open, allocate, and read for you.

The next more complicated alternative is to convert to PKCS#8 but still PEM: same as about but omit `-outform der` (and use a file name that indicates PEM, to avoid confusion). Then in Java read *that* file as *characters* (with a `Reader`, usually `BufferedReader`, not a `Stream`), discard the `BEGIN` and `END` lines, concatenate all the lines between, and convert them from base64 to `byte[]`: in Java8 you have `java.util.Base64`, before that you can use `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`.

To read the file you have in standard Java is harder. You could read the PEM-armored PKCS#1 and convert to binary PKCS#1, then "wrap" the PKCS#1 into PKCS#8 by building the DER encoding, but that's a good bit more complicated than what you've demonstrated familiarity with. Or you could parse the PKCS#1 and use the components to construct your own implemenation of `RSAPrivateCrtKey` and use that directly (no factory), ditto.

The other alternative is to use the third-party library from http://www.BouncyCastle.org which has more flexible features for handling PEM files than standard Java. But you need to learn their API as well as the standard one, and if your program will run anywhere else you need to ensure BC is deployed with or as part of your program.